$R$-symmetry & $R$-parity naming
I wondered me what exactly the "R" in $R$-symmetry and $R$-parity means, i searched in some papers or asked some people at my faculty but no one is really sure about the R. I interpreted the "R" as "rotation", effectively that do the $R$-symmetry with the superfields in the superspace. If anyone has a answer with a source, this would be really nice and helpful!

Not an answer, but: the oldest reference I found with that term is to "A. Salam and J. Strathdee, Nucl. Phys. B 87 (1975) 85", but I can't access the contents. Also note, the same question immediately applies to "R-parity" and "R-charge".

Thank you for the reference!  But the author never used the word R-symmetry but I found another reference, Nucl.Phys.B 90 (1975) 104-124, where the word R-symmetry is for the first time used. And I think from the context, where he denoted the operator of the R-symmetry with "R", but R is only a arbitrary choosen letter for the Operator and because the operator is called with "R" the symmetry is called R-symmetry.

Nice. If you find it appropriate to do so, note that you can answer your own question. It will be of interest then to also cite the relevant parts from the paper you mention.

I finally found a answer. Long story short, the "R" in R-symmetry/R-parity was chosen arbitrarily. In reference Nucl.Phys.B 90 (1975) 104-124 the word "R-symmetry" was the first time used. That's it, the "R" has no deeper meaning.
